# Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!\,2^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$, find $ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)-e^x}{1-\cos x}$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!\,2^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$, find the value of $ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)-e^x}{1-\cos x}$

I couldn't think of anything more than $f(x)-e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}(\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}-1)$ which leads me to nowhere

Comment: Use L'Hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Taylor,
$$1-\cos(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^3 \frac{x^n}{n!2^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{48}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$f(x)-e^x=-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{7 x^3}{48}+O\left(x^4\right)$$